# Memory problems with pandas (understanding memory issues)

Tags: python, database, pandas, memory, deep-learning

**The issue** is that I have 299 .csv files (each of 150-200 MB on average of millions of rows and 12 columns - that makes up a year of data (approx of 52 GB/year). I have 6 years and would like to finally concatenate all of them) which I want to concatenate into a single .csv file with python. As you may expect, I ran into memory errors when trying the following code (my machine has 16GB of RAM):

```
import os, gzip, pandas as pd, time

rootdir = "/home/eriz/Desktop/2012_try/01"

dataframe_total_list = []

counter = 0 

start = time.time()

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    dirs.sort()

for files_gz in files:

    with gzip.open(os.path.join(subdir, files_gz)) as f:

         df = pd.read_csv(f)
         dataframe_total_list.append(df)
         counter += 1
         print(counter)

total_result = pd.concat(dataframe_total_list)
total_result.to_csv("/home/eriz/Desktop/2012_try/01/01.csv", encoding="utf-8", index=False)
```

**My aim:** get a single .csv file to then use to train DL models and etc.

**My constraint:** I'm very new to this huge amounts of data, but I have done "part" of the work:

1. I know that multiprocessing will not help much in my development; it is a sequential job in which I need each task to complete so that I can start the following one. The main problem is memory run out.
2. I know that pandas works well with this, even with chunk size added. However, the memory problem is still there because the amount of data is huge.
3. I have tried to split the work into little tasks so that I don't run out of memory, but I will have it anyway later when concatenating.

**My questions:**

1. Is still possible to do this task with python/pandas in any other way I'm not aware of or I need to switch no matter what to a database approach? Could you advise which?
2. If the database approach is the only path, will I have problems when need to perform python-based operations to train the DL model? I mean, if I need to use pandas/numpy functions to transform the data, is that possible or will I have problems because of the file size?

Thanks a lot in advance and I would appreciate a lot a "more" in deep explanation of the topic.

**UPDATE 10/7/2018**

After trying and using the below code snippets that @mdurant pointed out I have learned a lot and corrected my perspective about `dask` and memory issues.

Lessons:

- `Dask` is there to be used AFTER the first pre-processing task (if it is the case that finally you end up with huge files and pandas struggles to load/process them). Once you have your "desired" mammoth file, you can load it into `dask.dataframe` object without any issue and process it.
- Memory related: 
  *first lesson* - come up with a procedure so that you don't need to concat all the files and you run out of memory; just process them looping and reducing their content by changing dtypes, dropping columns, resampling... *second lesson* - try to ONLY put into memory what you need, so that you don't run out. Third lesson - if any of the other lessons don't apply, just look for a EC2 instance, big data tools like Spark, SQL etc.

Thanks @mdurant and @gyx-hh for your time and guidance.

Comment: Take a look into `Dask` i've never used it before but it could be helpful for your case [DASK](https://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe.html)

Comment: @gyx-hh Thanks for the quick update; I will surely check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing: to take the contents of each CSV and concatenate into one huge CSV is simple enough, you do not need pandas or anything else for that (or even python)

```
outfile = open('outpath.csv', 'w')
for files_gz in files:
    with gzip.open(os.path.join(subdir, files_gz)) as f:
        for line in f:
            outfile.write(line)
outfile.close()
```

(you may want to ignore the first line of each CSV, if it has a header with column names).

To do processing on the data is harder. The reason is, that although Dask can read all the files and work on the set as a single data-frame, if *any* file results in more memory than your system can handle, processing will fail. This is because random-access doesn't mix with gzip compression.

The output file, however, is (presumably) uncompressed, so you can do:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv('outpath.csv')  # automatically chunks input
df[filter].groupby(fields).mean().compute()
```

Here, only the reference to `dd` and the `.compute()` are specific to dask.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation @mdurant. Lot to learn. I will check all this tomorrow and update on the same. One doubt arises now: if I process line by line and create a huge .csv file as you suggest, wouldn't I have the same problem of memory run out as the .csv file gets bigger and bigger or the output file is standing opened at disk space and not in RAM? It may be an ignorant question but it would be nice if you could address it.

Also, could you make a suggestion of an approach to follow if as you say "any file results in memory excess" when processing it? Thank you again.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand. If your purpose is to create a mammoth file, do as above. If your purpose is to analyse as a data-frame, load uncompressed file as shown, or load the set of gz files, if they are small enough each. Dask is smart about processing chunks as you need them, even if the total doesn't fit in memory; this is what dask is for.

Comment: Alright @mdurant. I will go deeply through all this and through dask docs to understand it better and return if any doubt and to confirm answer. Thank you for your time.